# form TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. in firefox. works great in chrome

Tags: forms, firefox, networking

I get TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. In firefox. the code works great in chrome.
What can I change so it will work in firefox too?

```
    // Send the data to the server as JSON
    fetch("zzsave_data13shirt.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            // Successful response, you can handle it here
            console.log("Data saved successfully");
        } else {
            // Handle errors here
            console.error("Error:", response.status, response.statusText);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error occurred during fetch:", error);
    // Log the error details for further debugging
   
});
```

I feel like i tried everything. Chatgpt is not very helpfull and I've searched the whole internet.